# About homotopy picture.

Tags: algebraic-topology

[image]

The image above is a part of Bredon's textbook. I want to know the explicit homotopy of the two pictures (Figure 3-4). I want to write an explicit homotopy using concatenation. In the first picture, there are two side triangles and one trapezoid. Since homotopy in trapezoid is given nothing to concern. But the problem is the side triangles. I don't know how to write down the homotopy of it. My guess of the homotopy of the left side triangle is eventually $p(3s)$ for $0\leq s\leq \frac{t}{3}$ and the middle one is $h_t(\frac{3}{3-2t}(s-\frac{t}{3}))$ for $\frac{t}{3}\leq s\leq 1-\frac{t}{3}$ where $h_t$ is a given homotopy. But I don't know explicitly why '$3s$' comes from. And I don't know how to write the homotopy of the right side triangle. And I can't even guess the explicit homotopy of the next picture. Could you please explain about this?